# How to control padding for value boxes created with bslib

Tags: css, r, bslib

I thought I could set a class for the value box to remove padding like this:

```r
bslib::value_box("test", "test", class = "p-0")
```

Or in a minimal Shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5),
  bslib::value_box("test", "test", class = "p-0")    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But if I do that, it removes only the padding for the bootstrap card:

[image]

I want to remove all the blue padding around the content, including the bootstrap card body.

The problem appears to be that `bslib::value_box()` function wraps content with `bslib::card_body_fill()`, and it doesn't look like there is a way to pass arguments through to `card_body_fill()`.

I can go into developer tools and search for "padding" and accomplish this:

[image]

Or I can add some CSS:

```css
.card-body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

But this will change the padding for all elements with class `card_body`. What if I want to target only a few value boxes?

Comment: You can write a css file that control this? Can You provide a complete minimal example here?!

Comment: I updated my question with some more details. What part of `bslib::value_box("test", "test", class = "p-0")` is not minimal or reproducible? My question is how to control padding for specific value boxes created with the `bslib` R package.

Comment: I meant are you using this for shiny or rmakdown?

Comment: I’m using this in a Shiny app currently.

Comment: And that's what I am asking. A minimal example of shiny app with just this box.

Comment: I added a minimal Shiny app to the question. But Shiny is not needed for the static HTML produced by `bslib::value_box()`. You can just run the `bslib::value_box()` function from the R console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class (suppose `nopad`) to `value_box`es for which you want to remove the padding of the content. Using developer tools, you would see that `value_box` contents are wrapped within a div with class `.value-box-area`. So Change the padding for css selector `div.nopad .value-box-area`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5),
  
  # css styles -------------------------------------------
  tags$head(
    # Note the wrapping of the string in HTML()
    tags$style(HTML("
      div.nopad .value-box-area {
        padding: 0;
      }
    "))
  ),
  # ------------------------------------------------------
  
  bslib::value_box("test", "test", class = "p-0 nopad"), # with class nopad
  
  bslib::value_box("test", "test", class = "p-0")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image: screenshot of shiny app]